# UITabBarController Modify [More ...] Appearance

Tags: iphone

I would like to know if there is a way to change the text in the [More ...] tab. 
With the code below I am able to change the text in the view, however the text in the tab remains the same. Is there a way to access it and change it's appearance.

```
tabBarController.moreNavigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Meer", "");
```

My second question is about the [Edit] button in the More view. The code below does not work.

```
tabBarController.moreNavigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Wijzigen" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:nil action:nil];
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I have answer for your second question.

You can set the property:

```
tabBarController.customizableViewControllers=nil
```

I hope the code would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like "system" UI strings are being displayed in English while your app is Dutch. The correct way to fix that is to change your app to use Dutch by default, by editing **Info.plist**:

```
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key><string>nl</string>
```

You're setting the title of the navigation item, which is only used in navigation bars. You could try setting the title of the view controller itself:

```
tabBarController.moreNavigationController.topViewController.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Meer",nil);
```

Or you can set the title of both the navigation item and tab bar items:

```
tabBarController.moreNavigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Meer",nil);
tabBarController.moreNavigationController.topViewController.tabBarItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Meer",nil);
```